# eigen3.0.5 upgrade to eigen 3.2.1 in Ubuntu Precise 12.04

Tags: ros, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
The stable version release of Eigen3 library in Ubuntu 12.04 is version 3.0.5. I am trying to upgrade eigen3 to atleast version 3.2.1. It is required for compilation of hierarchical branch of [g2o](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o) lib.

any suggestion how this can be solved.

thanks
nitin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151076/eigen3.0.5-upgrade-to-eigen-3.2.1-in-ubuntu-precise-12.04/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2014-04-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Nitin,

Yes you are correct, Ubuntu 12.04 stable uses Eigen 3.0.X. You can do any of the following;

- Clone eigen repo or download source and compile and install it on your machine
- Upgrade to 3.2 from the following deb provided by the yade crew - [http://packages.yade-dem.org/precise/libeigen3-dev_3.2.1-1~precise1_all.deb](http://packages.yade-dem.org/precise/libeigen3-dev_3.2.1-1%7Eprecise1_all.deb)
- Upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 or the latest stable Ubuntu 14.04 ( not really recommended until ROS indigo is fully stable on 14.04 )

Mrinal Kalakrishnan's STOMP libraries also require at least eigen 3.1. He got around the issue by catkinising eigen here https://github.com/kalakris/eigen. Though I wouldn't necessarily recommend that.

Hope this helps,
Jeremy

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Corbett](https://answers.ros.org/users/2912/jeremy-corbett/) with karma: 397 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2014-08-26**:
I am just wondering whether will upgrading the Eigen break other packages? May be because of API issue!